# Component pushed on StackView does not bind correctly

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, stackview

The example below illustrates my problem.
I create a small `Rectangle` at the top left and clicking on it toggles the color between red and green.

Next, I create a `StackView` and I push a `Rectangle` to the `StackView` and bind the color of this second Rectangle to the color of the top-left rectangle

Expected behavior would be that, clicking on the top-left `Rectangle` would also change the color of the `Rectangle` on the `StackView` since the color was binded. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Note that things work fine when pushing `stackRect2` to the stack (see line in comment)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 100
        height: 100
        focus: true

        color: toggle? "red":"green"
        property var toggle:false;
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: rect.toggle = !rect.toggle
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stack
        width: 100
        height:100
        anchors.left: rect.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 10

        Component.onCompleted: {
            stack.push ({item:stackRect, properties: {color:rect.color}})
            //stack.push ({item:stackRect2})
        }
    }

    Component {
        id:stackRect
        Rectangle {}
    }
    Component {
        id:stackRect2
        Rectangle {color:rect.color}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't say for sure but I would make a guess that the inner workings of StackView cause the binding to break. Probably something to do with this: _A property with a binding is automatically updated as necessary. However, if the property is later assigned a static value from a JavaScript statement, the binding will be removed._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apparently](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56125), this behavior is expected behavior and is in line with `Component::createObject()`.
Using

```
    stack.push (stackRect,  {color:Qt.binding(function() { return rect.color})})
```

works just fine.

Comment: see also https://forum.qt.io/topic/24152/solved-component-createobject-bindings-don-t-work/4 for a similar question on `Component::createObject`